# Laid waste or laid to waste?

Tags: grammar, phrase-usage

Which is correct:

> (Excerpt:)
>
> ''Historically, some 15% of that has been **laid waste** by poor management practices.

And(I thought):

> ''Historically, some 15% of that has been **laid to waste** by poor management practices.

I thought the correct phrasing was **laid to waste**, then I came across an article using **laid waste**. Is there really any difference?

Comment: They're just subtly different ways of saying the same thing. The first is a (passive) verb, and the second is the past perfect participle acting as an adjective phrase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Lay waste* has been an English phrase for a very long time: the OED gives an example from 1535. The OED describes this as involving the **adjective** "waste", which is reasonably common before a noun ("waste land", "waste water", "waste material"), but rare in other contexts, so it may not be readily recognised as a verbal complement (this is my analysis, not the OED's)

So, to me "laid waste" looks normal, as a set phrase, and "laid to waste" looks like an emendation by somebody who does not have a native experience of English.